# Заменить текст через регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

```
File.YJC366HVX3AGPBN663IPMKYHNM

Dir-308046B0AF4A39CB
```

Подскажите как можно заменить строки через `Regex.Replace(str, "pattern", ""))` чтобы по итоге было просто

```
File

Dir
```

Пытался так: `string newStr = Regex.Replace(str, @"-.+$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);` но не убирает `File.YJC366HVX3AGPBN663IPMKYHNM` а другой норм.

Или если можно обойтись без регулярных выражений и каким-то образов сделать замену тоо был бы рад. (`замена проводится в цикле foreach`)

Comment: `var newStr = str.Split(new[]{ '.', '-' })[0];`, в массив все возможные символы.

Comment: Паттерн: `@"[-.].+$"`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, работает! СПС.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, с пробелом работает, с точкой нет, так же проверял онлайн [Тест](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Всё прекрасно работает. Покажите код C#, как именно используете, с циклом foreach. / Откуда вдруг пробел взялся? В первоначальном условии нет его.